# Dynamically append detached div and scroll to it

Tags: jquery, html

The behavior I want to get is: On click on the top button, scroll down to the bottom div and detach the divs above. If then a button in the bottom div is clicked, reinsert the detached elements, scroll to the top div and detach the below ones.

So, in the end you have an animated scroll between divs and the other divs are detached/reinserted.

For some reason this isn't working for me. If you click on the top link in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zfn5f8w/) the behavior is as expected. But scrolling up isn't working; the detached elements are not reinserted! What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zfn5f8w/)

HTML

```
<div id="w">
    <div id="top">
        <a href='#bottom' id="scrollDown">Scroll down!</a>
    </div>
    <div id="space"></div>
    <div id="bottom">
        <a href="#top" id="scrollUp">Scroll up!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var t;
var s;
var b;

 jQuery('#scrollDown').on('click',function(){
    var w = jQuery('#w');
    if(b){
        w.prepend(b);
        b = null;
    }
    if(s){
        w.prepend(s);
        s = null;
    }
    var bottomPosition = jQuery('#bottom').position().top;
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:bottomPosition},1000,'swing',function(){
        t = jQuery('#top').detach();
        s = jQuery('#space').detach();
    }); 
    return false;
 });

jQuery('#scrollUp').on('click',function(){
    var w = jQuery('#w');
    if(s){
        w.prepend(s);
        s = null;
    }
    if(t){
        w.prepend(t);
        t = null;
    }    
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},1000,'swing',function(){
        b = jQuery('#bottom').detach();
        s = jQuery('#space').detach();
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

CSS

```
div { display:block; }

#top {
    height: 500px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #AAA;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#space {
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #336688;
}

#bottom {
    width:100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you complicating it using `.detach()`. Won't toggling `height: 0px` work for you?

Comment: I thought it might be better to remove the elements from the dom tree to get better performance. There's a lot of stuff in the top and bottom div!
Anyway, as a general question, I wonder why it isn't working as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i played around with the code and came up with this solution

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m0bd1xdu/)**

It seems that you had not initialised `t`, `s`, and `b` and were assigning them to `jQuery(element).detach()` and not `jQuery(element)` itself. So you could not prepend them later on.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think that would be necessary. From the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) it didn't become clear that such a thing would be necessary. For simpler examples like the one given there it just works as I tried it...
But thank you! I spent a lot of time not finding the problem :D

Comment: Maybe, because you're into the code atm, do you have an idea to prevent the jump to the page bottom after scrolling down to #bottom and detaching the #top and #space ? :S

Comment: I gave every div including html and body a height of 100%

Comment: Yes that's great. And with an additional content div of fixed height with `overflow:auto` in the '#bottom' div it would still be possible to have the content larger than the window height, and make it scrollable!
Thank you again!